# html & javascript: multiple checkboxes run same function for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want `chkbox1` to call a javascript function for `txtbox1`, `chkbox2` to call the same function but for `txtbox2`, and so on.

To take it a step further, I want all checkboxes checked in their default state and I want the functions to run when unchecked.

How can I achieve this?

I only know simple way for one checkbox:

```js
function OnChangeCheckbox(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    alert("The check box is checked.");
  } else {
    alert("The check box is not checked.");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked onclick="OnChangeCheckbox (this)" />
<label for="checkbox">uncheck box</label>
```

Comment: What does you mean **chkbox1 to call a javascript function for txtbox1**

Answer (score 4):

If your checkboxes and textboxes have something in common then you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk1" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk2" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk3" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chk4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />

<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
<input type="text" id="txt4" />

<script>
    function myFunction(el) {
       var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));

        if(el.checked) {
            txt.value = 'checked';
        }
        else
            txt.value = 'unchecked';
    }
</script>
```

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));
    if(el.checked) {
      txt.value = 'checked';
    }else{
      txt.value = 'unchecked';
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="chk1" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
  <input type="text" id="txt1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="chk2" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
  <input type="text" id="txt2" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="chk3" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
  <input type="text" id="txt3" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="chk4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
  <input type="text" id="txt4" />
</div>
```

Comment: @gibberish thank you for edit and sorry for mistype.

Comment: OMG, this is it! Perfect, my code was so much longer than this. THANK YOU! I don't know how it works though. How does it know that chk1 goes with txt1 and so on?

Comment: In your code you create checkboxes and textboxes in such way that you can replace 'txt' for 'chk' in ID to access them.

Comment: Okay, I got that part, but how do I run a function instead of just entering text. Example: I want to do this:  jQuery(function($){
   $("#chk1").mask("99-9999");  
});    
            }
            else {     
    
    jQuery(function($){
   $("#chk1").mask("999999?**");

Comment: You need a strategy how to map a checkbox to a certain textbox. You can use my example or invent your own. Similar id's is the simplest approach. You can add, for example, `data-textbox="some-tb-id"` to a checkbox and use it inside the function.

Comment: Did I answer your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

## Update Answer

hi, i just update my answer, so your function run if unchecked and get the value of checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" checked value="1" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="2" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="3" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />

<script>
    function myFunction(e) {

        if(e.checked == false) {
            alert('this box unchecked | value = ' + e.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That is not what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @ScottyGdog hi, please check i update my answer, i just read that you want to call function when some box unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate functions

```
function OnChangeCheckbox1(checkbox) {
..
}

<input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked onclick="OnChangeCheckbox1(this)" />
<label for="checkbox">uncheck box</label>

function OnChangeCheckbox2(checkbox) {
..
}

<input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked onclick="OnChangeCheckbox2 (this)" />
<label for="checkbox">uncheck box</label>
```

Comment: Hey, that worked, but it seems inefficient, because I want to repeat this 9 times. This is what I have:  <script type="text/javascript">

  function OnChangeCheckbox1(checkbox) {

            if (checkbox.checked) {      
    jQuery(function($){
   $("#jobnumber-j1").mask("99-9999");   
   });    
            }
            else {     
    jQuery(function($){
   $("#jobnumber-j1").mask("999999?**");  
   });      
            }
        }
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="check_filter">

    <div id="filter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">XYZ</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">WAS</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">DEF</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked'));
       if(isChecked == false){
switch (id) {
    case check1:
        txtbox1();
        break; 
    case check2:
       txtbox2();
        break; 
    default: 
        defaultFunction();
}
}
    });    
});
```